# PHP in_array() horrible performance. Fatest way to search array for value

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following simple code to test against collision on a primary key I am creating:

```
$machine_ids = array();

for($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++) {
    //Generate machine id returns a 15 character alphanumeric string
    $mid = Functions::generate_machine_id();

    if(in_array($mid, $machine_ids)) {
        die("Collision!");
    } else {
        $machine_ids[] = $mid;  
    }
}

die("Success!");
```

Any idea why this is taking many minutes to run? Anyway to speed it up?

Comment: Have you profiled that `in_array` is the culprit and not `Functions::generate_machine_id()`?

Comment: You have the code for `Functions::generate_machine_id` handy?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
for($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++) 
{
  //Generate machine id returns a 15 character alphanumeric string
  $mid = Functions::generate_machine_id();
  if (isset($machine_ids[$mid]))
  {
    die("Collision!");
  }
  $machine_ids[$mid] = true;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

For this, use `$mid` as keys, and dummy value as value. Specifically, instead of

```
if(in_array($mid, $machine_ids)) {
    die("Collision!");
} else {
    $machine_ids[] = $mid;  
}
```

use

```
if(isset($machine_ids[$mid])) {
    die("Collision!");
} else {
    $machine_ids[$mid] = 1;  
}
```

At the end you can extract the array you originally wanted with `array_keys($machine_ids)`.

This should be much faster. If it is still slow, then your `Functions::generate_machine_id()` is slow.

**EDITED** to add `isset` as per comments.

Comment: Beat me to it. :) Though you should use `isset($machine_ids[$mid])`.

Comment: Agree with deceze, and I believe `if($machine_ids[$mid])` will return false (not really a collision) if the value is integer 0, empty string, NULL, etc. In any case `isset()` is the way to go. However, I just noticed OP said it will always be a 15 char alphanum.

Comment: @deceze: Any reason? Is the performance hit of `isset` lower than performance hit of implicit conversion to boolean? Or is it theoretic - since in PHP `0` is also false, which would differ from `isset`? (in this case, all we have are empties and ones, so it's safe)

Comment: @Amadan: It will also generate a notice when `$machine_ids[$mid]` is not defined.

Comment: @Amadan As Wesley said, you'll get tons of notices this way, which take time to trigger as well. This triggering may slow down the script quite significantly and annoy the watching user to boot.

Comment: I see. I didn't know that. It's been a while since I did PHP regularly :)

Comment: Either way, `in_array()` is eating clearly up resources unnecessarily, looking through a bigger and bigger array... I'm also a bit amused with `die("Collision!");` :D

Comment: @Wesley: `in_array` would definitely be a problem, but I don't know whether it's the only one. If he's generating 100000 MD5 hashes, it's probably not going to be done in a millisecond. :)

Answer (score 3):

Checking for array membership is a O(n) operation, since you have to compare the value to every element in the array. After you add a whole bunch of stuff to the array, naturally it gets slower.

If you need to do a whole bunch of membership tests, as is the case here, you should use a different data structure that supports O(1) membership tests, such as a hash.

Answer (score 2):

Refactor your code so that it uses a associated array to hold the machine IDs and use `isset` to check

```
if( isset($machine_id[$mid]) ) die("Collision");

$machine_ids[$mid] = $mid;
```

Using `isset` should be faster

Answer (score 1):

If you need best performance for your case, you need store your data as array key and
use `isset` or `array_key_exists`(*since php >= 7.4 `array_key_exists` is now as fast as `isset`*) instead `in_array`.

> **Attention**. It is true that isset on a hash map is faster than searching through an array for a value (in_array), but keep in mind
> that converting an array of values, ["foo", "bar", "baz"], to a hash
> map, ["foo" => true, "bar" => true, "baz" => true], incurs a memory
> cost (as well as potentially constructing the hash map, depending on
> how and when you do it). As with all things, you'll have to weigh the
> pros & cons for each case to determine if a hash map or array (list)
> of values works best for your needs. This isn't specific to PHP but
> more of a general problem space of computer science.

And some performance tests from https://gist.github.com/alcaeus/536156663fac96744eba77b3e133e50a

```
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);

function testPerformance($name, Closure $closure, $runs = 1000000)
{
    $start = microtime(true);
    for (; $runs > 0; $runs--)
    {
        $closure();
    }
    $end = microtime(true);

    printf("Function call %s took %.5f seconds\n", $name, $end - $start);
}

$items = [1111111];
for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++) {
    $items[] = rand(0, 1000000);
}
$items = array_unique($items);
shuffle($items);

$assocItems = array_combine($items, array_fill(0, count($items), true));

$in_array = function () use ($items) {
    in_array(1111111, $items);
};

$isset = function () use ($assocItems) {
    isset($items[1111111]);
};

$array_key_exists = function () use ($assocItems) {
    array_key_exists(1111111, $assocItems);
};

testPerformance('in_array', $in_array, 100000);
testPerformance('isset', $isset, 100000);
testPerformance('array_key_exists', $array_key_exists, 100000);
```

Output:

```
Function call in_array took 5.01030 seconds
Function call isset took 0.00627 seconds
Function call array_key_exists took 0.00620 seconds
```