# Quick ways to optimize PHP code

Tags: php

I'm curious if there's any low hanging fruit to speed up a PHP script.

For example, is one of these better/faster than the other?

```
//Code 1
echo 'Hello ' . 'World';


//Code 2
echo 'Hello ';
echo 'World';
```

Are there other ways to clean up code and make it a tad faster? Is it even worth it?

Comment: Using a comma instead of a dot is known to give a faster compilation.

Comment: You can remove all comments and write all the code on one line. I know the function in_array can be slow depending on the situation/array size. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093890/php-in-array-horrible-performance-fatest-way-to-search-array-for-value

Comment: Don't ask, just bench it. For other not worth looking into* benchmarks: http://www.phpbench.com *-unless you are running facebook or something similar in scale.

Comment: for something like this it would be faster to just write basic html then using php at all. don't use php unless you need dynamic variables.

Comment: ["We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://hungred.com/useful-information/php-micro-optimization-tips/

But then you have to balance that with how readable and understandable your code is.

Comment: Wow, pretty much every low hanging fruit on one page, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the accept! However even as I replied I was shaking my head.  As said here (and many other places) this kind of micro-optimisation is rarely needed, you are much better off trying to reduce the number of trips to the database, or work out how you can cache some of your data.  These have massive effects. Its like spending big money on fancy car tyres to reduce drag when you have a roofrack on your car and you drive with the windows down. If you ARE into this though, look at XDebug and http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler . Good luck!

Comment: Cool... actually this comment is part of the answer I was looking for: "Is it even worth it?" Also, the suggestion to skip PHP microoptimization and look for DB optimization. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The fastest is probably

```
echo "Hello ", "World";
```

if you have to echo two seperate strings/variables, as this avoids having to concatenate the strings. However, the difference is probably unnoticeable for any reasonable sized application.

But remember

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil
>    - Donald Knuth

However, it is nice to know the echo-comma syntax and use it where possible.

Comment: according this, http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/04/optimize-php-code/ your code should be optimized.